# Assembling output into one shape when loop is used in python script in QGIS3?

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, iteration, output

I’m writing a new processing script for QGIS 3 using a for loop in the code.
The "problem" is that if I try to iterate N times, N shapes are generated in output. I would like to have only one shape as output.
Below a simplified example is reported, but I think it's enough to understand with your help how to solve.
[image: from model designer]

Below the code that the model designer automatically generates and on which I introduced a 'for' loop as test.

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('lines', 'lines', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterVectorLayer('points', 'points', types=[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint], defaultValue=None))
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink('AddFieldAppleOut', 'add field apple out', type=QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry, createByDefault=True, supportsAppend=True, defaultValue=None))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, model_feedback):
    # Use a multi-step feedback, so that individual child algorithm progress reports are adjusted for the
    # overall progress through the model
    feedback = QgsProcessingMultiStepFeedback(4, model_feedback)
    results = {}
    outputs = {}
    
    ##########introducing loop to test output :-)
    for k in range (1,3):
        # Buffer
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': 6000,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'INPUT': parameters['points'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Buffer'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Extract by location
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['lines'],
            'INTERSECT': outputs['Buffer']['OUTPUT'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractByLocation'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Dissolve
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD': [''],
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractByLocation']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Dissolve'] = processing.run('native:dissolve', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # add field apple
        alg_params = {
            'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
            'FIELD_NAME': 'add_colo',
            'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
            'FIELD_TYPE': 2,
            'FORMULA': '\'apple\'',
            'INPUT': outputs['Dissolve']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': parameters['AddFieldAppleOut']
        }
        outputs['AddFieldApple'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
       
       #-----------------------------------#
       #N times, N outputs! :-( I try to introduce code here, without success
       #-----------------------------------#
        results['AddFieldAppleOut'] = outputs['AddFieldApple']['OUTPUT']
    return results

def name(self):
    return 'LoopingOutput'

def displayName(self):
    return 'LoopingOutput'

def group(self):
    return ''

def groupId(self):
    return ''

def createInstance(self):
    return LoopingOutput()
```

How can I have only one shape as output?